# Printing integer array in C (with loop) yields unexpected sequence of numbers

Tags: c, arrays, printf

In a program I am writing I have declared this variable:

```
 #define SIZE 5

 long  int clockNum [SIZE] = {98401, 526488, 765349, 34645, 127615};
```

If I would like to print this so that the output was:

```
098401
526488
765349
034645
127615
```

How Would I do this? I tried the statement below but it doesnt seem to work..

```
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {

    printf ("%li\n",&clockNum[i]);
    }

    return(0);
```

The output I get looks like:

```
-1076048964
-1076048960
-1076048956
-1076048952
-1076048948
```

Comment: printf ("%5i\n",&clockNum[i]); Try this statement

Comment: do you need that extra zero on the left of the first number? 098401
526488
765349
034645
127615

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove the `&` from printf and let see

```
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
   printf ("%li\n",clockNum[i]);
}
```

here in `printf` `&` give the address value of the variable

Comment: Perfect! I added a bit to it to get the leading zeros.                       printf ("%0.6li\n",clockNum[i]);

Answer (score 3):

Remove `&` sign from line `printf ("%li\n",&clockNum[i]);` because it gives address of given value or varible not actual value.

Answer (score 2):

Change your call to `printf` to something like: `printf ("%li\n",clockNum[i]);`.

As it is right now, you're trying to print the address instead of the value of the number (but since the type you're passing doesn't match the type you specified in the format string, result is undefined behavior).

If you really need to print the leading zero(s) so all the values come out as 6 digits, you also want to change your format string to something like `%6.6li`.